# How to fix git issue "Support for password authentication was removed"?

Tags: android-studio, github

I am using android studio interface to commit, push, pull and fetch operations in github. Now i am seeing this error message. How to solve? How to generate token to solve this issue?

[image]

Comment: you could use Personal access token as mentioned [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68781992/5562367) or use ssh authentication as an alternative, i find it more convenient. read more about using ssh auth [here](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/about-ssh)

Answer (score 0):

#For MAC OS
Click on the Spotlight icon (magnifying glass) on the right side of the menu bar. Type Keychain access then press the Enter key to launch the app - In Keychain Access, search for github.com -- Find the internet password entry for github.com-- Edit or delete the entry accordingly - You are done

#For Windows OS
Go to Credential Manager from Control Panel - Windows Credentials - find git:https://github.com - Edit - On Password replace with your Github Personal Access Taken -- You are Done